# Planning to start Iphone game in Unity engine..Suggestions/Experiences?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am new on unity and iphone game development. I have been instructed to make a game for iphone. After alot of research and google I am now thinking to use Unity3d game engine as it compiles code for almost every device plus no extensive coding.

What do you people suggest am I planning right ?
Is there any issues playing unity game on Iphone ?
Would I need to modify it in Xcode also ?

Pls suggest me abt it. Thnx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have worked with Unity3d, but not for iPhone, but Unity seems to be the right direction because of its simplicity and sheer quality of the engine. Unity3d is great for beginners as well as for low-medium budget game projects. Highly recommended.

By the way this question doesn't belong here, use [GameDev SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) for non-programming game development issues.

Answer (score -1):

The Unity engine is a great choice because it makes it easy to visually assemble your levels. While it does help you organize and integrate your game assets and components, don't think you can get by with minimal coding if you plan to build a game of any kind of scope. You'll still need to code, just not excessively.

Answer (score -1):

I started developing iPhone apps with Unity3d as well. First of all, I want to say that deployment with Unity3d is extremely hard compared to making your app with swift, objective-c/objective-c++, and Xcode. Unity3d was easier for me to grip on to and create games with than my experiences with Xcode though. The only part where I would give Unity3d a 0 out of 5 stars is deployment. Some reasons why I say this is resolution, auto-generated Xcode errors, low-quality iPhone deployment help for indie developers, and many other reasons. I created a tilting ball game like a maze game that I wanted to put on the App Store. However, Apple kept rejecting my app due to the horrible build Unity3d made of my project. After 5 continuous tries to put my app on the app store, I decided to go an easier developer way and to head towards learning the foundation programming language of iOS apps, Swift. I would say that Swift was a very horrible experience compared to Unity3d. Unity3d had a very easy C# editor and drag and drop user interface. Xcode didn't have that much though. In Xcode, creating new scenes, making transitions and many other things were a very intimidating task for me. I don't want for you to go with the same problems I did so I would really recommend you starting with Xcode and not going straight to Unity3d. If you do go to Unity3d, remember what I said.